# problems deploying redmine on Heroku i18n gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, heroku, redmine

I'm having issues getting redmine deployed on heroku. I've set it up as described in tutorials, and have it running locally without a problem. It pushes to heroku, but I get an app crashed error when I try to visit the site via browser. The error reads:

Missing the i18n 0.4.2 gem. Please `gem install -v=0.4.2 i18n`
(in /disk1/home/slugs/387746_aba0dc0_7ca6-e147f05a-688f-4291-903f-994eb1a4080f/mnt)

I've tried installing the gem, but that hasn't worked. Why is this happening and what will make it go away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got this to work by adding creating a file named Gemfile to the root of the project directory with the following contents.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '2.3.5'
gem 'i18n', '0.4.2'
```

Comment: Since this worked for you, can you please mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

for any others reading this, [here is my guide to installing Redmine on Heroku](http://bayleshanks.com/tips-computer-programming-redmineOnHeroku).